# Specify search fields for some cases DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have these fields for search in my `ViewSet`:
`search_fields = ('username', 'name', 'surname')`
When I want to search a user, I append URL with something like  `?search=usertest`. And it will search on 3 provided fields. Is there a way to specify a field where to search for some custom cases, so that input will be searched only, for example, on `name` field?

Comment: One possible solution is to use regex in python

Comment: @bigbounty how?

Comment: Why don't you use [filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) ?